# Recommended way to create variable, flexible dataframe?

Tags: r

Given a table with a variety of values and lengths, what's the best way to create a dataframe for columnar analysis?

Example, given an unlabeled CSV that looks like this:

```
A,B,A,C
A,B,C,D,E,F
B,C,A,B,F,F,F
A,B
B,C,D
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,Y,X,Z,AA,AB,AC
```

The goal will be to eventually assign a value to each letter based on what position it appears in.

Given the variable, and unknown length of the rows, how should I approach this problem? Set up a dataframe with an absurdly large number of columns as a placeholder?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Can you give a sample how the output should look like based on the first row, A, B, A, C?

Comment: Once you have the data loaded into a data frame, you could use `library(tidyverse); df %>% rowid_to_column("row") %>% separate_rows(V1, sep = ",")` to convert it to a long table with a row for every value, noting which row it started in. That should be reshapeable into any format you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to read each row as an element in a vector using `readLines()` -

```
x <- readLines("test.csv") # add appropriate path to the file
x
[1] "A,B,A,C"              "A,B,C,D,E,F"                                                 
[3] "B,C,A,B,F,F,F"        "A,B"                                                         
[5] "B,C,D"                "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,Y,X,Z,AA,AB,AC"
```

Now you can manipulate each element of this vector as you wish and then assemble the results in your desired structure. This way you don't have to *"Set up a dataframe with an absurdly large number of columns as a placeholder"*.